# how to communicate peer to peer in hyperledger fabric local network

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I've created hyperledger fabric local network in system(Ubuntu) which contains 4 peers using docker composer, config.yml file.
I'm able to create users in a single peer by using membersrvc. But, how to do transactions between two users.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understant very well your question. What do you mean? Do you want to communicate with the peers?

- The peers communicate among them through the **channels**. When you define a channel, you decide who are going to be part of it. Then, the transactions that are executed against that channel are viewd by all the members of the channel.
- Users call the Peers and do the transactions
- You don't do the transactions among Peers or between users. You **call to a smartcontract** (chaincode in Hyperledger) that you have **installed in a channel**